# Facebook login button showing "Undefined" instead of "Login"

Tags: authentication, oauth, facebook-opengraph, facebook-login

The facebook login button implemented in my website was showing the text as "undefined" instead of "Login" in firefox latest version in Windows 7. So to fix that i went to get the latest code from the Plugin page at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/.

Its showing "undefined" in the preview button also. What should be done to get it fixed?

I am ready to use the latest code given but it looks like a problem with facebook JS to me.

Sorry! I don't have enough rep to post an image :P

Comment: Here is the pic for FB developers site: https://twitter.com/ravindranathk/status/263184150452920320/photo/1/large

Comment: If it is also happening on the Plugin page, you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it to fb and referenced Ravi's screenshot.  Here's my bug report, if you want to subscribe -
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383067995106570

Comment: Thanks Suzanne :) i tried to file a bug first but i didn't know how to do that :P

Comment: Now please click on my link above and subscribe to the bug!  It might help get it fixed faster!

Answer (score 0):

This problem once frustrated me and i searched for the solution in many sites. I find one site to be very helpful for me as my problem is solved and solution is easy to understand. so i am sharing with you guys. just go to [www.facebookloginhelp.net](http://facebookloginhelp.net) and get your problem solved.